# Putting Breakpoint on Register Write in Trace32

Tags: debugging, embedded, real-time, trace32, lauterbach

I see an option for putting a breakpoint on read or write of a register when creating a new breakpoint, but it is greyed out. How do I get to select that option and how would I write, for example, that I want to break when something writes a value of 0x60002806 or > 0x60002000 to register A2?

Comment: Which CPU is this for? I believe there needs to be hardware support in the CPU for read/write breakpoints to work.

Comment: You're probably right. It's an Aurix TC277TF

Comment: I don't know the specifics of that particular MCU, but since it is one of them 32 bit automotive safety monsters, it definitely has on-chip hardware breakpoints for read/write, as well as on-chip trace. So I guess this is a Trace32 issue. It is very important for Trace32 to have a correct script (.cmm file) executed at start-up, matching the specific MCU. This script should set up the MMU among other things. If the MMU is not set correctly, you'll get all kinds of weird behavior and missing features. If you post the script you are using, maybe some Trace32 guru can help you out further.

Answer (score 2):

I never saw a processor on chip debug implementation that allows such functionality, to stop when a CPU reg have a value.

On ARM, when facing these troubles I use to obtain a ETM trace with code and data enabled, and after the register gets that value, stop the capture and look for current value of the register along the trace with a search on it.